# What is the size of a bool in PHP?

Tags: php, size, boolean

What is the size of a bool in PHP?

For an int, it's easy to determine

```
echo PHP_INT_SIZE;
```

I got 4 so 8 bytes or 32 bits.  What about for a bool type?  Thanks.

Comment: It should be one byte I think?

Comment: This is when I wish `sizeof` did the same thing in PHP as it did in C and C++.

Comment: @alex Why one byte when a bit would do?

Comment: @Phil I just assumed one byte would be the minimum. Something like `00000001`. This is why I should ignore these questions :)

Comment: Curious why this matters (beyond curiosity). Unless you're Facebook (in which case the compilation to C++ changes things anyway) I just can't see the memory size of a bool mattering at all in PHP.

Comment: @Phil According to the [answer by onteria_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972039/what-is-the-size-of-a-bool-in-php/5972077#5972077), I was right :)

Comment: @alex Wasn't saying you were wrong. Seems like a waste of 7 bits though

Comment: @Phil Yeah, but being written in C, there isn't an easy way to set up a one bit type is there?

Comment: @BoltClock In the case of `sizeof(TRUE)`, it reports back the correct number (though I understand not using the correct measure) :)

Comment: @Phil Modern computers as we know them cannot operate on a per-bit resolution in RAM.  Everything is done in terms of bytes.  This is a limitation of the physical CPU architecture.  This is different in physical storage, of course, but even then you'd need a complex algorithm to encode/decode things down to a single bit level of resolution because data is pulled from physical storage into RAM by the byte.  This would make it computationally expensive and not worth doing so.  Ever coded in assembly language?  Much can be learned from doing so.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The size of a bool can be found by looking at the php source directory `Zend/zend_types.h`:

```
typedef unsigned char zend_bool;
```

With the size of unsigned char being 1 byte.

Comment: This has little to do with how much memory a PHP boolean occupies. This `zend_types.h` snippet just defines some C compiler type abstractions.