# Does a boolean value in PHP take up only 1 bit of memory?

Tags: php, memory

As the question states, would the following array require 5 bits of memory?

```
$flags = array(true, false, true, false, false);
```

[EDIT]: Apologies just found [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972039/what-is-the-size-of-a-bool-in-php).

Comment: Short answer: No. [Google "PHP zval"](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+zval) to find out why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each element in the array stored in a separate memory location, you also need to store the hashtable for the array, along with the keys, so NOOOO, it's going to be a *lot* more.

Answer (score 2):

No. PHP has internal metadata attached to every variable/array element definined. PHP does not support bit fields directly, so the smallest ACTUAL allocation is a byte, plus metadata overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is an application that uses less than system arcitecture's data `word` as a minimum data storage unit.

But I am sure it shouldn't be your concern at all.

Comment: That's without a doubt wrong.
1) A 'word' is generally 16 bit, regardless of architecture (from 8 bit to 64 bit processors)
2) It is common practice to store data efficiently and use memory efficiently, including how a single bit is stored.
3) Typically a byte isn't uncommon for single bit storage, sometimes even more but when working larger amounts of bits (for example databases, cryptography, math, etc) a bit isn't unlikely to take exactly that space.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the php interpreter. The standard interpreter is extremely wasteful, although this is not uncommon for a dynamic language. The massive overhead is caused by garbage collection, and the dynamic nature of every value; since the contents of an array can take arbitrary values of arbitrary types (i.e. you can write `$ar[1] = 's';`), the type and additional metainformation must be stored.

With the following test script:

```
<?php
$n = 20000000;

$ar = array();
$i = 0;
$before = memory_get_usage();
for ($i = 0;$i < $n;$i++) {
    $ar[] = ($i % 2 == 0);
}
$after = memory_get_usage();

echo 'Using ' . ($after - $before) . ' Bytes for ' . $n . ' values';
echo ', per value: ' . (($after - $before) / $n) . "\n";
```

I get about **150** Bytes per array entry (x64, php 5.4.0-2). This seems to be at the higher end of implementations; [ideone](http://ideone.com/aXkrj) reports **73 Bytes/entry** (php 5.2.11), and so does [codepad](http://codepad.org/DEkqmkIk).